# Problem of using \setmainfont{Times}: \textit{text} = \textit\textbf{text}

Tags: fontspec, times

When I use the following package and command in my book

```
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Times}
```

and use the command of `\textit{text}`, the text automatically shows as:
[image]

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: There are so many versions of Times that it’s hard to say without having access to the version installed on your machine. But generally, if `fontspec` doesn’t automatically sort out the italic, the bold, the bold italic, etc., you can help it along as described in §2.1 of the current `fontspec` manual.

Comment: What happens if you use a Times font contained in your TeX distribution: `\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Termes}` or `\setmainfont{stix}` for example?

Comment: Please indicate which operating system you use (since `Times` is a system font). Please also indicate whether you use XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX.

Comment: @Mico macOS High Sierra, XeLaTeX